Obtaining an approximate identity for a $C^\ast$-algebra from an approximate identity on its unitization
I'm interested in the construction of an approximate identity for a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$. Proofs that I've read often take $A$ to be unital and imply that the non-unital case is readily deduced from the unital one. However, I don't see how to make the leap.
Let $A_+$ be the unitization of $A$. Suppose we have constructed a net $(e_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \Lambda} \subseteq A_+$ with $e_\lambda$ self-adjoint, $\sigma(e_\lambda) \subseteq [0, 1)$ and $x e_\lambda \to x$ for all $x \in A_+$. Hence in particular for all $x \in A$ (where $A$ is identified with its image in $A_+$). It is clear that $x e_\lambda \in A$ for each $\lambda$. However, write $e_\lambda = (y_\lambda, \mu_\lambda)$ for some net $(y_\lambda)$ in $A$ and net of complex scalars $(\mu_\lambda)$. What the convergence then really says is that $x y_\lambda + \mu_\lambda x \to x$. I don't see any reason why we should need, e.g. $\mu_\lambda x \to 0$, and indeed I'd suspect that not to be the case. So it's not immediately clear to me how to extract $e'_\lambda \in A$ such that $x e_\lambda' \to x$.
This problem is rectified by working in the unitization $A_+$ throughout the proof (and considering the set $\mathcal E = \{(e, 0) : e \text { normal}, \sigma(e) \subseteq [0, 1)\}$, say, as a subset of $A_+$), regardless of whether $A$ is unital or not. Though I am still curious how to deduce the non-unital case from the unital case. The question Show a $C^*$-algebra admits an approximate kind of identity. seems to be mainly concerned with whether $A$ would be an ideal in $A_+$ (?), which doesn't concern me.

You cannot deduce the non-unital case from the unital case. $e_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ would be an approximate identity consisting of elements with spectra in $[0, 1)$ in a unital $C^\ast$-algebra, say, but it certainly doesn’t help at all in producing an approximate identity for the non-unital case.

Also, your $\mathcal{E}$ would not be an approximate identity for $A_+$, only $A$. No approximate identity of $A$ can be an approximate identity of $A_+$, as $A$ is an ideal in $A_+$. This means any approximate identity of $A_+$ necessarily has a constant part (in fact, a constant part going to $1$), so I don’t think it’s possible to extract an approximate identity of $A$ from any approximate identity of $A_+$.

The proof I’ve read on this never assumes unitality, so I don’t know for sure. But I’d assume the proof you read either only uses the fact that any $C^\ast$-algebra has a unitization to simplify certain arguments, but the approximate identity itself is constructed in, and for, the not necessarily unital $A$. Or alternatively they prove that any ideal in a unital $C^\ast$ algebra admits an approximate identity, then use the fact that $A$ is an ideal in the unital $C^\ast$-algebra $A_+$.

@DavidGao Note I write $(e, 0)$ not $e$ in the definition of $\mathcal E$ so this shouldn't be an approximate identity for $A_+$. I believed I could trace the proof in e.g. Conway operator theory to get a proof that you get the convergence in $A_+$ (for each $x \in A$) and hence in $A$) but I may be mistaken. Will give it a go later.

I’m aware $\mathcal{E}$ consists of $(e, 0)$, which is precisely why I’m a bit confused. Your $\mathcal{E}$ is a subset of $A$. If you’re only showing $\lim e_\lambda x = x$ for $x \in A$, then everything happens in $A$ and this really has nothing to do with $A_+$ anymore. In particular, there’s no approximate identity of $A_+$ involved at any stage in this. So what exactly is the question?

@DavidGao yeah so by doing this we find an approximate identity for $A$, whether $A$ is unital or not (we can consider $A_+$ in both cases). Have I understood this correctly? Was really just checking that I wasn't missing some way to go straight from a proof on unital algebras to non-unital algebras and as you point out there isn't.

That is correct, yes. $\mathcal{E}$ is an approximate identity of $A$, regardless of unitality (in fact, I think sometimes it’s called the canonical approximate identity). And there isn’t any way to go from the unital case to the non-unital case, as I commented before.

@DavidGao Great, that resolves my concerns, thanks!
